# Explain Linq Microsoft Select - Indexed [Example]

Tags: c#, linq

I'm running throuth Microsoft's [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758#SelectSimple1), and I'm stumped on how this query knows how to assign the correct `int` value to the correct `int` field:

```
public void Linq12()
{
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

    var numsInPlace = numbers.Select((num, index) => new { Num = num, InPlace = (num == index) });

    Console.WriteLine("Number: In-place?");
    foreach (var n in numsInPlace)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", n.Num, n.InPlace);
    }
}
```

I saw in [SO #336758](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082701) that there have been errors in the examples before, but it is much more likely that I am just missing something.

Could someone explain this and how the compiler knows how to interpret this data correctly?

**EDIT:**

OK, I think my confusion comes from the LINQ extension that enables the *Select* feature to work. The **Func** and two **int** parameters `IEnumerable<TResult> IEnumerable<int>.Select(Func<int,int,TResult> selector)` are most likely the key to my lack of understanding.

[image]

Comment: Funny, I updated my answer with just that :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking of but the `Select` iterates over the list starting at index 0. If the value of the element at the current index is equal to the index it will set the `InPlace` property in the anonymous object to true. My guess is that the code above prints true for 3, 6 and 7, right?

It would also make it easier to explain if you write what you don't understand.

Jon Skeet has written a series of blog post where he implement linq, read about `Select` here: [Reimplementation of Select](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-3-quot-select-quot-and-a-rename.aspx)

**UPDATE:** I noticed in one of your comment to one of the other comments and it seems like it is the lambda and not linq itself that is confusing you. If you read Skeet's blog post you see that `Select` has two overloads:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector) 

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector)
```

The `Select` with index matches the second overload. As you can see it is an extension of `IEnumerable<TSource>` which in your case is the list of `ints` and therefor you are calling the `Select` on an `IEnumerable<int>` and the signature of `Select` becomes: `Select<int, TResult>(this IEnumerable<int> source, Func<int, int, TResult> selector)`. As you can see I changed `TSource` against `int`, since that is the generic type of your `IEnumerable<int>`. I still have `TResult` since you are using anonymous type. So that might explain some parts?

Comment: LOL. I'm actually sitting here with that book by Jon, reading his *Extension methods* in Chapter 10. I got confused on all this stuff, so I googled for more examples.

Comment: :). But as I said, if you are more precise in your question it is easier to answer it.

Comment: Question has been edited ...with a picture! Is there a good way to grasp LINQ expressions while gaining insight to all of LINQ's built in `Func` commands? It could take me years to get this stuff down! :(

Comment: I don't think it is linq that you are struggling with, I think it is the lambda expressions in combination with generics and extension methods. So study up on lambdas first and a new world will open up for you :). Here is the [msdn resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) on lambdas.

Comment: Just a comment: The title of the link you provided says *C# Programming Guide*, but the default code language is VB. {sigh}

Answer (score 2):

Looks correct to me.

First you have an **anonymous type** with Num and InPlace being created.  Then the **LINQ Select** is just iterating over the elements with the element and the index of that element.  If you were to rewrite it without linq and anonymous classes, it would look like this:

```
class NumsInPlace
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public bool InPlace { get; set; }
}
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };

List<NumsInPlace> numsInPlace = new List<int>();
for (int index = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    int num = numers[index];
    numsInPlace.Add(new NumsInPlace() { Num = num, InPlace = (index == num) });
}

Console.WriteLine("Number: In-place?");
foreach (var n in numsInPlace)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", n.Num, n.InPlace);
}
```

The [MSDN on Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) has the details, but the projection function (num, index) always has the item first, then the index second (if supplied).

Comment: But, how does the compiler know that **LINQ Select** is using the `index` value as an index to the array? I have no doubt that the example is sound; I simply have a hard time understanding how I could create LINQ expressions such that the compiler understand me, too.

Answer (score 2):

The lambda expression `(num, index) => new { Num = num, InPlace = (num == index) }` is executed once for each element in the input sequence and passed the item and it's index as the arguments.

**Update**

[Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) can be implicitly typed, that is, from the required type, the compiler can figure out (or imply) what types you intend the arguments to be.

```
(num, index) => new { Num = num, InPlace = (num == index) }
```

is equivalent to

```
someAnonymousType MyMethod(int num, int index)
{
    return new 
    {
        Num = num,
        InPlace = (num == index)
    };
}
```

obviously you can't write the latter because you can't type the name of an anonymous type, but the compiler can ;)

The compiler knows this because [the overload of `Select` that you're using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) accepts a `Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>`, this is a `Func` that takes, two arguments of type `TSource` (the type of your `IEnumberable<T>`, in this case `int`) and an Int32 (which represents the index) and returns an object of `TResult`, being whatever you choose to return from your function, in this case, an anonymous type.

The lambda can be cast to the required type and therefore it *just works*.

Comment: Hi Greg. This is exactly the line I am asking about. How does the compiler know that `num` and `index` are `int` values? LINQ confuses me greatly.

Answer (score 2):

> how does the compiler know that LINQ Select is using the index value as an index to the array?

The compiler doesn't know about index values.  The implementation of that overload of Select knows about index values.

```
//all the compiler sees is a method that accepts 2 int parameters and returns a bool.
Func<int, int, bool> twoIntFunc = (x, y) => (x == y);

//The compiler sees there's an overload of Enumerable.Select which accepts such a method.
IEnumerable<bool> query = numbers.Select(twoIntFunc);
```

Enumerable.Select's [implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) does the rest of the work by calling that method with the appropriate parameters.

> The first argument to selector represents the element to process. The second argument to selector represents the zero-based index of that element in the source sequence.

So - Select will call your method with (5, 0) first, then Select calls it with (4, 1).

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in the select is the index, which increments as the compiler traverses the array of numbers.  The compiler will see

```
num index   num = index
5   0   false
4   1   false
1   2   false
3   3   true
9   4   false
8   5   false
6   6   true
7   7   true
2   8   false
0   9   false
```

Comment: How does the compiler know what `index` is? I am having a hard time grasping how it knows what LINQ is saying.

Answer (score 0):

It provides true for 3,6 and 7. You need to remember it starts with the index at 0.